# How can I save UTF-8 files with a Byte Order Mark?

Tags: character-encoding, unicode

I am trying to configure Emacs to save UTF-8 files with a Byte Order Mark. (Yes, I know that the [BOM is evil](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#2-2-character-encoding) and [unnecessary](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.0.0/ch02.pdf#page=30) [for UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223926/2747593) files. However, [Microsoft has decided](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [they know better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4655335/2747593), so I want to make sure I'm able to save files with BOM.)

However, for some reason my choice of `utf-8-with-signature` for `buffer-file-coding-system` won't stick when I save the file.

I'm using Emacs 24.5.1 on Windows 10. To reproduce:

1. `emacs -Q`
2. Open a file (optionally one that already has a BOM).
3. `(setq buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-with-signature)` (Or `M-x set-buffer-file-coding-system RET utf-8-with-signature RET`.)
4. `C-x C-s`
5. `C-h v buffer-file-coding-system`. It is now set to `utf-8-dos`. I also verified that the existing BOM was removed from the file.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Pityingly I can only give an answer to the second question "How can I fix this".

Let emacs guess the file encoding after finding the file via `html-mode-hook` and use it for saving the file via `save-buffer-coding-system`.
You can do that with the following lisp snippet in your init file.

```el
(defun TZA-html-set-coding-system ()
  "Retain the byte order marker of `html-mode' buffers."
  (setq save-buffer-coding-system buffer-file-coding-system))

(add-hook 'html-mode-hook #'TZA-html-set-coding-system)
```

Comment: This seems like a useful workaround. I no longer do much development on Windows, so it might be a while before I can get around to testing it.

Comment: Is there a way to apply this to all buffers instead of just those with a given mode?

Comment: @ScottWeldon You can use `after-change-major-mode-hook` instead of `html-mode-hook`. But I think this is not necessary. From what I read about the problem it is special to `html-mode-hook`. Note, that it is not limited to Windows.

Comment: Okay, thanks. IIRC, I wasn't using `html-mode` when I ran into this problem; I think it was `web-mode` and/or `csharp-mode`.